# How to switch background of button in RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have buttons in my Recyclerview what is want to do is whenever user clicks first button the background of that button should changed and when user clicks next button that time first button should appear as normal button. how to do it? Please help me.
Here is my sample code:

```
     @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AreaRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder Viewholder, final int position) {

        final GetAreaAdapter getAreaAdapter1 =  getAreaAdapter.get(position);


        Viewholder.btn_name.setText(getAreaAdapter1.getBtn_name());
        setImageIntoButton( Viewholder.btn_name,getAreaAdapter1.isSelected());
        Viewholder.btn_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getAreaAdapter1.setSelected(!getAreaAdapter1.isSelected());
                setImageIntoButton(Viewholder.btn_name,getAreaAdapter1.isSelected());
                Viewholder.btn_name.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ripple_effect);
            }
        });



    }
  private void setImageIntoButton(Button buttonView,boolean isSelected){
        if(isSelected)
            buttonView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ripple_effect);

        else
            buttonView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use State-List drawables

create a xml file in your drawable directory
and add something like
button_bg.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/some_drawable_for_pressed_state" 
android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/default_drawable"/>
</selector>
```

and set it as background for the button.

`android:background="@drawable/button_bg.xml"`.